# Document tags and moving across libraries

Tags: document-library, move, tagging

If you create columns in library views to capture specific information pertaining to documents and then move the document to a brand new library that is not set up with the same columns, do you lose those "tags" or column information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need a workflow or some code in order to not have to manually fill out the columns on another list.  Also, if you do use a workflow to transfer meta data from one list to the next, make sure the field types are the same between the two lists.  The do not have to be named the same, just have the same field type, single line, date, lookup, etc.

Comment: One interesting thing I did find was that if you "move" as opposed to "copy" files, the tags will remain.